# Refactor rename broken in Intellij IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, refactoring, rename

Somehow, I managed to break my refactoring capabilities in Intellij IDEA 12. I have somehow disabled it for my project. Renaming a member through <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> doesn't work. The inline edit box is not drawn, nothing happens.

I know of the refactoring settings in `Settings -> Editor`, `Enable in-place mode` and `Preselect old name` are both checked.

It has to be some kind of project setting. I checked by creating a test project, adding some member and renaming it, which works perfectly.

What setting am I looking for? Or could my project be broken?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

There is no way to turn refactoring off in the settings. My guess is that the project's cache/indexes are corrupted. I had a case once where refactoring, especially renames, stopped working. A re-index solved it for me. Go to *File >Invalidate Caches*, invalidate your caches, restart IDEA, and let IDEA re-index the project (progress is shown in the bottom status bar right of center). Then try the refactoring.

If that does not solve it, take a look in the logs (*Help > Show Log*) and see if there is any indication in there as to the cause of the issue.

Comment: In te meantime, I downloaded the Intellij 13 EAP version. That obviously 'solved' my problem. Thanks for your answer, will certainly try your suggestions will I ever run into this problem again.

Comment: Intellij 13 also has problems if its index was corrupted due code changes (ieg. if you switch git branch). Invalidate Caches and Restart helps!

Comment: @verhage On IDEA 13 I'm experiencing different types of bugs, all of them cause code corruption. I'm thinking now on switching back to 12.

Comment: I'm using IDEA14, this solution does not work for me, still stuck/not responding once I press refactor(rename) or Al+F7(Find usage), until I delete the whole install and reinstall it. I'm on Windows 7.

Comment: I'm on IntelliJ 2018.2.4 and in-place Rename still fails for some variables. File > Invalidate caches... > Invalidate and Restart does not solve it. :^(

Answer (score 12):

Fo all the MacOS users, do not forget to access `Settings -> Keyboard` and turn on the flag for the option `Use all F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys`. E.g.:

[image]

Otherwise IntelliJ will not get the focus to use the <kbd>F4</kbd> key.

Answer (score 1):

Following step worked for me:

From your IDE, go to: `Preferences -> Project Structure -> Add Content Root`, then select the folder you want to use.

Comment: I tried everything but in the end, this is what worked! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

None of the above steps worked for me in IDEA 2021.2.4 (Ultimate Edition). I got the following error message when trying to rename a file and its usages:

```
Cannot perform refactoring. Selected file is not located inside the project.
```

Instead, I had to **create a new module**.

*File* > *Project Structure* > *Modules* > *Add (+)* > *Import module* > *Select <root_folder_of_your_project>*

This reindexed the whole project, which took a couple of minutes, and restored the *Refactor* > *Rename* functionality.

Answer (score 0):

waite for some time it can be due to running Indexing

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. Attempting to rename particular classes, I couldn't work out the common factor, would result in a partial refactor process (e.g. some namespace references updated, file name updated but not the class etc). I tried the usual things such as clearing index and a "fresh" installation but I just couldn't get it to work.

The only thing that actually worked was totally removing the Toolbox app, PhpStorm plus all configuration and cache directories. Instructions [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/uninstall.html).

Once I did that, I installed using the same disk image I used earlier and I was presented with new UI. I'm not sure if the Toolbox was interfering or my configuration was in some weird state but these steps resolved my issue.